# Selection count in extjs works too slow

Tags: performance, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I use standart Ext.grid.Panel in extJs.
I need to select up to 500 rows in grid, and I want to know how many rows I have selected. I do it in such way:

```
    multiSelect: true,
    listeners:
    {
        'select':
        function( combo, record)
        {
            mainNS.app.pagingTB.items.get('selected-sited').update(' count of selected rows: ' + 
            mainNS.app.mainGrid.getSelectionModel().getCount())
        }
    },
```

But it works too slow, how can I optimize this operation?

Comment: Getting the selection count is super cheap, just asking for a property on the collection. You need to provide more detail.

Comment: But if I remove that listener (nothing else), selection of 500 rows lasts less than 1 second. With listener it lasts more than 10 seconds even on good PC. Maybe problem is than it counts for each selected row (500 times in my case)?

Comment: So, you're calling `.select(foo)` where `foo` contains 500~ or so items?

Comment: user selects first row, then shift+click on the last row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select event will fire for every record during a multiple selection. So if n rows are being selected at once, that means you're updating the content and, most importantly, triggering a layout n times.

You have 2 options:

1. Listen to the `selectionchange` event, which will fire only once for a batch of selections.
2. Add `buffer: 1` as an option to the select event, so it will buffer the event from firing until the last selection has occurred.

No. 1 is the preferred solution.